# How can I find the number of functions,that satisfy some conditions?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $k,n \in \mathbb{N} \text{ with } k \leq n$. $[k]=\{1, \dots , k \}$ and $[n]=\{ 1, \dots , n\}$.
How can I find:

- the number of functions from $[k]$ to $[n]$
- the number of functions from $[k]$ to $[n]$,that are $1-1$
- the number of functions from $[k]$ to $[n]$,that are strictly increasing
- the number of functions $f$ from $[k]$ to $[n]$,for which $f(i)=f(k+1-i) , \forall i \in [k]$

Comment: Don't you have _any_ thoughts about any of the subquestions?

Comment: For the last question, if $k=2m$, we can let $f(i)$ be anything from $1$ to $n$ for any $i$ between $1$ and $m$. If $k=2m+1$ we can let $f(i)$ be arbitrary between $1$ and $n$ for any $i\le m+1$.

Answer (score 0):

First one is easy: $n^k$. (You choose the value for $f(i)$ from $[n]$, for $i=1,\dots k$.)

Second almost as easy: $n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-k+1)$. (You choose the first value, then second from the rest and so on. Notice that if $k>n$, product contains $0$ and you don't have any injective functions, so that works out.)

Third one: Some recursive method might be helpful here. Let's say the number of such functions is $F(k,n)$. Then

$$F(1,n) = n$$
$$F(k,k) = 1$$
$$F(k,n) = \sum_{j=1}^{n-k+1} F(k-1, n-j)$$

(Add the number of ways when you let $f(1) = 1$, $f(1) = 2$ and so on to the last possible, that is $f(1) = n-k+1$ and use recursion to set the rest values for $f$.)

You can use $2d$-table to list the values for $F(k,n)$ easily.

Was the fourth one already answered in the comments? It seems too cumbersome for me to think about. The indeces might be wrong in my answer for the third one also, but I think the recursive idea should be fine. Make the table and fill it out...

EDIT: When I filled out the table I actually noticed that $F(k,n) = {n \choose k}$. Explanation for this: The order of the values of $f$ is fixed by the strict increasingness, you can only choose the places where you place the values.